# Like a friend's photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, photo

How to support "like friends photos" for Facebook user using Facebook APIs or FQLs?

Comment: I think you'll need to give a bit more information as to what language you want to use etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it you would like? You want to add the "LIKE" button to another site? or... err

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I am developing an iPad application in which logged-in user's friends photos will be displayed. The user should be allowed to Like the photo of his friend. I wanted to support this Like feature programmatically. Should I use Graph API, Facebook Query Language or REST APIs for this.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is deprecated, and the Graph API should be used whenever it´s possible. FQL only if there is no other/good way with the Graph API.

About liking Photos, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

> You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes
>   connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters
>   necessary.